# Eclipse Force.com plugin Installation issue

Tags: ide, eclipse

I am trying to install Force.com Eclipse IDE Plugin for Eclipse Juno 4.2 but i am getting error like  Force.com IDE 31.0.0.201406301722 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 31.0.0.201406301722) requires 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui 3.8.2' but it could not be found .

Can someone please help me with this error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Eclipse is best supported by the documentation and help available from eclipse.org

Comment: @crmprogdev I disagree, I've seen this issue couple of times and would see the Q & A as a valuable reference for future developers trying to install the plugin with the ide. The documentation doesn't cover this failure or error code.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error with Juno before, I would suggest installing Kepler instead since the plugin supports both versions. Make sure you choose 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' distribution.

More [info](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation) here.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Anup . I tried to install Force.com plugin on Kepler too but its prompting the same error.

Comment: Are you installing the plugin behind a firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Eclipse classic Standard/SDK and update to salesforce plugin with http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42. It worked for me. Once you updated with the force.com plugin, you can later update the eclipse sdk to the latest version if needed.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-helios.php
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-42/junor